# Sorting a dictionary by contents in Python

Tags: python

I have a library called WinP

```
WinP = {}
```

WinP has 119 Lists, labeled WinP[1], WinP[2], ... WinP[119]. Each list has 1 number in it. I want to sort the lists by the number inside of each list.

Ideally I'd like to return a list of numbers like [45, 13, 110, 8, ... 50] representing the Lists in WinP arranged by the value inside

Answer (score 1):

If you want a sorted list of all values you can [itertools.chain](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) the values:

```
from itertools import chain

print(sorted(chain.from_iterable(WinP.values())))
```

If you want the keys sorted by the values, pass the key `WinP.get` to sorted which will sort the keys by value:

```
print(sorted(WinP,key=WinP.get))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sorted(WinP, key=lambda k: WinP[k][0])
```

Dictionaries in Python can be treated as iterables of their keys. You can sort the keys based on the first element of their corresponding value, which are one-element lists. This is just a general approach that would sort lists of any size with any number of elements based on a single one of those elements.

However, because lists are already sortable in lexicographic order, and because all dictionaries have a method called `get`, this can be shortened to the clever expression in Padraic Cunningham's answer.

```
sorted(WinP, key=WinP.get)
```

Demo:

```
>>> from random import randint
>>> WinP = dict(zip(range(1,10), ([randint(1,10)] for _ in range(1,10))))
>>> WinP
{1: [9], 2: [5], 3: [3], 4: [1], 5: [2], 6: [3], 7: [4], 8: [8], 9: [10]}
>>> sorted(WinP, key=lambda k: WinP[k][0])
[4, 5, 3, 6, 7, 2, 8, 1, 9]
>>> sorted(WinP, key=WinP.get)
[4, 5, 3, 6, 7, 2, 8, 1, 9]
```